# Store image in firebase and Send Image URL to mongodb REACT

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to send an image from my mern application to firebase and at the same time also want to store that image's url in my mongodb but there is some problem with the synchronicity of the logic , what i am doing right now is i am storing the image details in a usestate on the "onchange" and later i have made a 'post' button which is when clicked sends the image to firebase and also gives me url of that image using **downloadurl** and also i save that url in a usestate and then send that to my server through that same onclick function now the problem is the **downloadurl** is called inside a function so it runs late and the fetch request runs first so it doesnot gets the url and i know this because i am loggin this in my console , here is my code:-

```
const handleimage = (e)=>{
        setpost({...post,image:e.target.files[0]})
    }
const post_send = async(e)=>{
        // onclick function

        e.preventDefault(); 

        if(post.image == null)
        return;
        const date = Date.now();

        if(post.image == null)
            return;
        storage.ref(`/images/${post.image.name}`).put(post.image)
        .on("state_changed" , alert("success") , alert , ()=>{
            storage.ref('images').child(post.image.name).getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
                setpost({...post,image:url})
                console.log(url)
            })
        });
        
       setstate({...state,first:'none',addphoto:'none'})
       
        console.log('a')
       const res = await fetch('/post',{
           method:'POST',
           headers:{
               'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
               'x-auth-token' : localStorage.getItem('token')
           },
           body:JSON.stringify({
            post
           }),
       })
   }
```

Comment: Why not just POST to MongoDb in the continuation from Firebase action?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen How?

Comment: put it in the `then` instead of trying to use `setpost`